# Alamorefile upload images timeout when using many threads

Tags: alamofire, rx-swift

I'm using moya to upload many images by using OperationQueue to control maxConcurrentOperationCount. Supposing i have 100 images, uploading 5 images everytime. Alamorefire timeout sets to 10 seconds.

Uploading one image is very fast, nerver triggering timeout. But when i uploading 100 images using the method below, even using multithread, it triggering timeout. Why? 
Thank you!

```
queue = OperationQueue()
            queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
            var i = 0
            for image in photos {
                autoreleasepool {
                    let operation:BlockOperation = BlockOperation(block: {
                        [weak self] in
                        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
                        print("hyl cur thread %@", Thread.current)
                        strongSelf.uploadImage(image)
                        return
                    })
                    i += 1
                    queue.addOperation(operation)
                }
            }
```

```
private func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        AladdinProvider.rx.request(.upload(access_token: UserInfo.instance.access_token!, file_name: "file_name", data: image)).asObservable().mapJSON().mapObject(type: AlbumDatas.self).subscribe(onNext: {
            [weak self] result in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
            // TODO success

            }, onError: {
                 error in
                print(\(error))

        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, this is an issue with creating and resuming `URLSessionTask`s before they're allowed to run. This is exacerbated by Alamofire, which creates the `URLSessionTask`s immediately upon creation of a corresponding `*Request` value. Increasing the timeout of the `URLRequest`s you're using for image downloads could help. A more thorough solution would be to stop creating your Alamofire requests immediately, instead only creating them as the first few requests complete. This should prevent the associated tasks from timing out.